# After waking-up, how do you know if your mac was hibernating (fully powered off like Windows PC) and not sleeping?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, sleep-wake, hibernate

Not sure if my Macbookpro Retina 2015 is waking up from sleep, safesleep or hibernation.

I have enabled hibernatemode 25 (via terminal command: sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25). pmset -g shows hibernatemode is indeed 25.

Is this mode the equivalent of the Windows 7 hibernate and or, the hibernate button on the 'Deepsleep' widget/mac app http://www.axoniclabs.com/DeepSleep/ or the other 'Deep Sleep' app's sleep button http://deepsleep.free.fr ?

Comment: If you have to type your file vault password, you hibernated. If you aren't using FileVault, you should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wake a Mac from hibernation, RAM got written to disk and power removed from memory. Then, at wake, it gets read back into RAM.  This takes longer than normal, or standby sleep (depending on the delay set) and is visible at wake time by showing an Apple symbol and progress bar underneath (white time markers filling up).
Also running the following command in Terminal:

```
pmset -g log | grep -i "wake from"
```

will show the sleep states, e.g.

> Wake from Hibernate 
>   Wake from Normal Sleep 
>   Wake from Standby

The last time I saw the 'Deepsleep' widget in action, it did the same as hibernation, i.e. write to disk and remove power from memory.
PS.
As the man pages (`man pmset`) hint in the quote below, `standby` and `autopoweroff` should be set to the value "0", via the same `pmset` command you've used to set hibernatemode, to set your MacBook Pro to use hibernation instead of normal, or standby sleep (I would also disable any Energy Saver System Preferences to wake your Mac periodically):

> For example, on desktops that support standby a hibernation image
>   will be written after the specified standbydelay time. To disable
>   hibernation images completely, ensure hibernatemode standby and
>   autopoweroff are all set to 0.

PPS.  But please also consider the following thread here on AskDifferent:
[How to add hibernate mode to MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126669/how-to-add-hibernate-mode-to-macbook-pro)

Comment: Thank  you for your answer redarm. The log produced shows all sleep states were "Wake from Standby". Hibernatemode is set to 25 and Standbydelay to 1. However, I still get the same results. I wanted the mac to actually hibernate like a Windows PC does. I was told macs can actually do this and is evident when seeing the grey screen (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201635). Still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Btw Redarm, are you sure you've interpreted the man pages correctly? It says if you want to disable hibernation you should set values to 0, which is the opposite of what you mentioned in your PS.

Comment: Hi Redarm, I disabled standby via the sudo pmset -a standby 0 command. I now get the grey screen with the progress bar. Howeover, when I run the pmset -g log | grep -i "wake from" command you mentioned, the log still shows Wake from Standby...I thought the grey screen with the progress bar means waking from hibernate. According to your command that is not the case.

Comment: Do you have a link for your pmset manual? When I run the man pmset command I get a manual similar if no the same as this one: (http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pmset/), which doesn't have the paragraph you  quoted below.

Comment: Did you also set `autopoweroff` to 0? Both `standby` and `autopoweroff` set a delay, after which the system hibernates; so to achieve hibernation straight away, they would have to be 0.  With both set to 0 I see "wake from hibernation" in the log on a mid 2014 retina MacBook Pro straight away. No devices were attached - any drives attached will be ejected.

Comment: Online there are only older (Mavericks) man pages:[https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html].  Another thread of interest on AskDifferent about the differences of `standby` and `autopoweroff`: [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113954/difference-between-autopoweroff-and-standby-in-pmset].

Comment: `Standby` sleep is another form of hibernation.  The Mac will hibernate after a set delay. The relevant link to Apple's explanation: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202124

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I managed to do it! It's weird because according to the pmset manual autopoweroff is only valid when on AC mode ("The system will not power off if any external devices are connected, if the system is on battery power, or if the system is bound to a network..."). Or perhaps I misread read it and the opposite is true when deactivating autopoweroff. Anyway, now I just need to configure the settings to go to sleep as usual (e.g. when the machine is left for a short while) and then go to hibernate when I need it to power off. Thank you again @Redarm.

Comment: The part you quoted (autopoweroff) has been removed in newer El Capitan's man pages.

Comment: Now I need to stop it from switching off the screen and going to hibernate after X seconds. I will try and configure some settings or ask a new question if that fails. Thank you again @Redarm. Some people including app developers thought I wouldn't be able to get the Wake from Hibernate result. Thanks for clarifying about the man pages. I guess that's another benefit of using El Capitan. Perhaps it's time to upgrade.